# How to install libstdc++.i686 on RedHat RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

```
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

...

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/gcc-4.8.2/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyc from install of libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-4.8.2/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyo from install of libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64
```

What does this tell me and how can I fix it?

Here's the reason why I need it:
https://docs.bmc.com/docs/brid91/en/preparing-a-unix-environment-610402414.html#PreparingaUNIXenvironment-PreparingtoinstallonRedHatLinux

Yes, I did try to cheat and just linked the 64bit

```
# ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /lib/libstdc++.so.6

# ls -lad libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 25. Dez 09:53 libstdc++.so.6 -> /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

but got this as a result:

```
./arcache: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Comment: This tells you that, assuming the packages are from the same source, since the package version and release are the same the package maintainer has allowed a small bug to slip through.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same issue. I was able to use yum to download the RPM, then force install the rpm.

```
$ sudo yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/var/tmp/ libstdc++.i686
$ sudo rpm -ivh --force --nodeps /var/tmp/libstdc++-<VERSION>.i686.rpm
```

yum

--downloadonly - only download the package into an RPM

--downloaddir - download an RPM to the specified dir

rpm

--ivh - install/verbose log/print hashes for progress

--force - ignore existing installs, this is what ignores the above error

--nodeps - ignore dependencies

Comment: Why do this rather than the shorter commands?

Comment: Because the shorter command will fail per the original question. In case you mean why do the options, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It says you i686 package not match with you x86_64 package(must with same version number), update the x86_64 package first, then try again:

```
yum update -y libstdc++.x86_64
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to expand on some of the previous answers as they will not install all of the dependencies.

```
yum install libstdc++.x86_64 -y
rpm -e --nodeps libstdc++.x86_64
rm -f /var/tmp/libstdc*
yum install libstdc++.i686 -y
rpm -e --nodeps libstdc++.i686
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/var/tmp/ libstdc++.i686
yum install libstdc++.x86_64 -y
rpm -ivh --force --nodeps /var/tmp/libstdc++*
rm -f /var/tmp/libstdc*
```

Answer (score 0):

simple comment but the update for the x86_64 appears to me to be clearly the right answer!  Small edit for me would be to just

`yum update -y libstdc++.x86_64 libstdc++.i686`